# Azure AKS-API (Preview Authorization Failure

Tags: api, azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

In attempting to create an Azure Container Service (AKS) cluster using the same account information for which I can create a cluster via the portal, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in generic_views: 500 Internal Server Error: Creating cluster
>   7f3b1ed3-1996-4558-97d1-1672d87d56e1 failed with following reason:
>
> CloudError(\"The client '09ad439c-5569-4e9b-8b23-3311d6837a21' with
>   object id '09ad439c-5569-4e9b-8b23-3311d6837a21' does not have
>   authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/21a6a032-5d60-45a6-ae51-c5f0c4007995/resourceGroups/MC_BruceContainerGroup_BruceCluster1_eastus/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/7f3b1ed3-1996-4558-97d1-1672d87d56e1'.\",)

I tried adding (IAM) permissions for Azure Container Services to the RG used, and to the APP, but it didn't work. What do you think could be causing this error?

Comment: Could you give more details about what are oyu trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved this issue by adding Access Control (IAM) permissions for ALL Azure Applications to the subscription... I am not sure adding which one resolved the issue, but I suspect it was the Azure Container Service.